# Is there any way to know the height of the status bar? XAMARIN IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am creating an app and I was wondering if there's a method that gets the height of the status bar in the iOS. I am currently making it manually, and if it there was something like: this.view.frame.getstatusbar() would be perfect. The goal is to make a blue bar after the status bar, like an upper menu.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Height of status bar in iOS is 20.0 in default . And you can also get it by the following code .

```
var size = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame;
var height = size.Height;
var width = size.Width;
```